# Why is my group opener a mess? (Version 12.0)

Tags: front-end

I am using Version 12.0, and found the arrow for the group opener is a mess. What happened?
[image]

Comment: Click on the affected cells, to the right on the brackets, and press "Cntrl+Shift+E". This will open up the expression of the cell, and then I recommend you post here, updating your answer for more help. (Someone may know the reason why without it, but with it will allow for more to provide input). Plus then you get to see how your cells are actually formed in the Wolfram Language!

Comment: Seems to me that there's some file encoding issue (`â€  ï` is a common sequence of characters that you get when a UTF-8 file has been read and saved as another encoding like LATIN-1). Perhaps consider trying to use a tool like [`ftfy`](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on your notebook file.